# Convert 32-bit Floating Points to 16-bit PCM range

Tags: python, audio

I have some data generated by the javascript HTML5 web audio api. It generates [Float32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array), an array of 32-bit Floating Points, between -1 and 1. I stream the data to my server using a websocket.

I need to convert the 32-bit floating points to 16-bit PCM range between -32768 and +32767 (16-bit signed integer). This then allows the data to be used as a wav file.

I'm having trouble converting. I suspect the answer is to use the struct module, but I can't get the correct formatting.

Comment: The `struct` module can't directly convert between these types. It can only unpack a 32-bit floating point value into a Python float and pack a Python int into a 16-bit integer. It also won't do the range conversion you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a sample Python 2.7 program that reads a file containing raw 32-bit floating point audio samples and creates a WAV file containing those samples converted 16-bit signed integer samples:

```
import sys
import array
import struct
import wave

def convert(fin, fout, chunk_size = 1024 * 1024):
    chunk_size *= 4    # convert from samples to bytes

    waveout = wave.open(fout, "wb")
    waveout.setparams((1, 2, 44100, 0, "NONE", ""))

    while True:
        raw_floats = fin.read(chunk_size)
        if raw_floats == "":
            return
        floats = array.array('f', raw_floats)
        samples = [sample * 32767
                   for sample in floats]
        raw_ints = struct.pack("<%dh" % len(samples), *samples)
        waveout.writeframes(raw_ints)

convert(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"), open(sys.argv[2], "wb"))
```

The code uses `array.array` to convert the 32-bit floating point samples to a Python floats because it should be a bit faster than `struct.unpack`. It also uses the native machine byte order, just like `Float32Array` does. It's not possible to use `array.array` to create the 16-bit integer samples because they need to use the little endian byte order regardless of the native machine order. The range conversion is handled by simple Python code.

Comment: thanks for the help. I've simplifed the code to this: https://gist.github.com/richtier/6b05b2bb3ceff20f3d9557227b8789c6, but when I use bytes as defined in here: https://pastebin.com/raw/yCQ8Bg5w I get he error `struct.error: required argument is not an integer` at this point `samples` look like e.g., `[505.00430237688124, 487.5382216461003, 471.0005183443427, 440.09429602883756]`, which makes sense because `samples` is a list of floats still

Comment: @rikAtee What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.5.2
on a separate note when I add the following, I think it starts behaving itself: `samples = [int(sample * 32767) for sample in floats]`

Comment: Yah, I'm using 2.7, which appears not to be as picky. Using `int(sample * 32767)` should solve the problem.